# bad request when trying to call POST function from controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have problems accessing a POST method from my controller class with Http.PostJsonAsync and always get back Bad request status error.However I have different controller classes with working examples where I do the exact same thing only with different data models and names, but the code is the same. I would be glad if someone can spot the error im doing.

I have the following function call:

```cs
private async Task AddAdditionalItem(string valueTest1, string valueDateTest1)
{
    article_list inputSQL = new article_list();
    inputSQL.articlename = valueTest1;
    inputSQL.date = valueDateTest1;

    var x = await Http.PostJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/api/article_list/create", inputSQL);
    Console.WriteLine(x.StatusCode);
}
```

The console output does return a bad request status code. However I cannot find whats wrong with my controller class:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class article_list_Controller : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SqlDbContext_test _dbContext;

    public article_list_Controller(SqlDbContext_test dbContext)
    {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create")]
    public async Task<bool> Create([FromBody] article_list article)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create");
        
        if(ModelState.IsValid){

            _dbContext.Add(article);
            try
            {
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My database context class looks like this:

```cs
public class SqlDbContext_test : DbContext
{
    public SqlDbContext_test(DbContextOptions<SqlDbContext_test> options) : base(options)
}
public DbSet<article_list> article_list {get;set;}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder){
    modelBuilder.Entity<article_list>().HasNoKey();
}
```

And finally my model class:

```cs
public class article_list
{
    #nullable enable
    public string? articlename 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }
    public string? date 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }
}
```

EDIT: this is my customHttpClient Method implementation:

```cs
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync<T>(string requestUri, T content)
{
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

    // Pass the handler to httpclient(from you are calling api)
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    string myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
    StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, stringContent);
    httpClient.Dispose();
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Please have a look on the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:2 With Existing Code:**

Method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync<T>(string requestUri, T content)
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

            // Pass the handler to httpclient(from you are calling api)
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            string myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, stringContent);
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            httpClient.Dispose();
            return response;
        }
```

How I Invoked Method:

```
            var requestURI = "http://localhost:5094/api/article_list/Create";
            article_list inputSQL = new article_list();
            inputSQL.articlename = "My First Value";
            inputSQL.date = "My Last Value";
            var callMethod = await PostJsonAsync(requestURI, inputSQL);
```

Final Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please check your did you invocked the method and passed the parameter. These are all of my investigations.

**Update:**
I am calling `AddAdditionalItem` method as following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            string param_1 = "First Parameter Value";
            string param_2 = "Second Parameter Value";

            var callAPI = AddAdditionalItem(param_1, param_2);
            return Ok(callAPI);
        }
```

> I have problems accessing a POST method from my controller class with
> Http.PostJsonAsync and always get back Bad request status error.

Well, based on your shared code snippet I have tried to reproduce your issue. But at the begining I noticed this snippet `Http.PostJsonAsync` which am not sure, if you are using any 3rd party library. However, I tried to continue with your code and got following compilation error:

[image]

I think we should call the API endpoint using `HttpClient` if I am not mistaken.

**Solution:**

I have tried to call your `article_list_Controller`  and `Create Action` and I have successfully got the 200 response along with value I have retured. Here  is the demo how I implement that:

**AddAdditionalItem Controller:**

```
public async Task AddAdditionalItem(string valueTest1, string valueDateTest1)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Setting Base address.  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost:5094/");
                // Initialization.  
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

                //Bind Model property
                article_list inputSQL = new article_list();
                inputSQL.articlename = valueTest1;
                inputSQL.date = valueDateTest1;
                //Call Endpoint
                response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/article_list/Create", inputSQL);
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                // Verification  
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Reading Response.  
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }


            }


        }
```

**API Controller:**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class article_listController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Create")]
        public async Task<bool> Create([FromBody] article_list article)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note: As per my findings, if you update your `PostAsJsonAsync` request with `HttpClient` it would return you expected response. For further details you can check our [official document how we can invocked  PostAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944682(v=vs.118))

Comment: hello, I forgot to add my CustomHttpClient class which extends HttpClient and there I defined the custom Method PostJsonAsync, which I will add to my original post. It's nothing special and almost the same thing you did but I still get a Bad Request response for no apparent reason. With another controller and different model I can casually send a post request to my controller which adds the data to my database but not with this particular data model article_list

Comment: Thanks for your response, would kindly try using my solution, so that it can be norrowed down where might be the issue. As you can see, I can successfully send request to API endpoint and gettting expected response.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get a badrequest and I tried using your solution with PostAsJsonAsync. Can you further show how you call AddAdditionalItem and how Index() is implemented? In my solution I am calling AddAdditionalItem("param1","param2") with an await operator inside a SaveDialog() function which gets called when I click a save button.

Comment: Sure, please check the updated answer, I have included already.

Comment: thanks for the update. When and where is index called?

Comment: I Just called it from browser as you can see on my shared output, main part is to invoke `AddAdditionalItem` and pass parameter within it. In addition, your this method `Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostJsonAsync<T>` causing the failure.

Comment: I have just tried yours one, in first few attempt it didn't worked, but now its working fine as well.

Comment: I am getting a invalid URI invalid port specified exception, which I do not get when I try to write other objects to my database using different controllers

Comment: I think, issue on passing parameter to your method. I am updating my answer with latest code snippet.

Comment: hello and sorry for the late reply. I have fixed the issue and it was because in my original code I used different names for my classes which i edited just for this post. In the original I had a name something like foo_bar_foo_bar with multiple underscores which was the reason I got a bad request as you somehow can't use multiple underscores for creating your URI

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, what is outside of our visibility is not considerable thus, community contributor always focus what been shared. Therefore, based on your code, I have provided the correct solution. So its up to you if you accept or failed to implement at your end. Another, point is  who tought this kind of class naming convension `foo_bar_foo_bar`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using multiple underscores as class names for my data model and parsing that as a URI which genereated a bad request. For some reason you can only use one underscore and not multiple. I changed my class names in my original code and fixed the problem that way. I only used one underscore in my code examples and thats why the error is not reproducable